# Compact Sets Metric Spaces

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Lets $(\Bbb R,|x-y|)$ be a metric space. By the Heine-Borel theorem, it obviously follows that $\Bbb Q$ is not a compact set. Now, if I were to consider $\Bbb Q \cap[-1,0]\subset\Bbb R$ is that a compact set or not? I'm not exactly sure of how I should approach such questions, can someone give me some sort of way to prove/disprove compactness in such cases?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Let $(r_n)$ be a sequence of rationals converging to $-\sqrt{2}/2$. Does there exist a subsequence converging in $\mathbb{Q} \cap [-1,0]$?

Answer (score 1):

A subset $A$ of $(\mathbb R, |\cdot|)$ is compact iff. it is *closed* and *bounded*.
While $[-1,0]\cap\mathbb Q$ is bounded, it's not closed, because it's closure is $[-1,0]$.

Answer (score 0):

In $\Bbb R$ compactness is equivalent to bring closed and bounded. Since, $\Bbb Q\cap [-1,0]$ is not closed, it is not compact.